# How to show a date in Arabic format?

Tags: 2013, xslt, variations

I have a list which contain a column, "Modified", which contain date and time of an item in the list.

When I display that list in my Arabic site then the date is displayed in English format, such as 24/02/2013.

Shouldn't SharePoint automatically show a date in Arabic format? Or do I have to manually replace English numbers with Arabic ones using [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)?

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I want to display in English but the site defaults to Arabic dates. The Region and Locale settings are set to the UK yet dates appear in Arabic. I found a way to change it at individual list level by editing the Library settings for each site (change the Modified column display format property to use the Standard, not the Friendly option), but I don't really want to go through every single Document library making manual changes. Does anyone know how to change the default language for the Friendly option? My SharePoint and user regions are UK, so it isn't that.

Comment: Please ask a new question at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask